# When I use OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' It still shows the double quotes

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import a dataset that includes some text fields that are enclosed by double quotes "sometext" but when I try to load the file it still shows the double quotes.

Here is the sql

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/Carlos/Desktop/smallData.txt'
into table acars
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@Date, @Time, flight, n_number, blk_id, msg_label, text_label, msg_text)
SET Date_Time = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@Date, ' ', @Time), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```

with this small data sample:

```
date_dd_mm_yyyy; time_est; flight; n_number; blk_id; msg_label; text_label; msg_text
01/03/2014; 00:02; XA0001; ..VQBZZ; 3; 15; ""; " (2N26451W 81508---100354---(Z"
01/03/2014; 00:04; CO1588; .N71411; 7; H1; "msg to/from terminal"; " #DFB96 0                    877"
01/03/2014; 00:12; XA0001; ..VQBZZ; 4; 15; ""; " (2N27038W 82483--- 94423---(Z"
```

the Problem is that I get this format back for all the lines:

```
| 2014-03-01 00:02:00 |  XA0001 |  ..VQBZZ |      3 |  15       |  ""                     |  " (2N26451W 81508---100354---(Z"                                                                |
```

basically it just doesn't do the `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` part

Comment: yes, the " are at the beginning and in the end, even in the null locations since it shows "" as shown above.

Comment: this does not change anything, the double quotes still show up